# How to create System Menu (mini control panel)

Tags: command-line, server, configuration, settings

I want to make system menu after login in my Ubuntu server like this image:

[image]

To change my Ethernet IP address, the local time and some other stuff important to me, I don't know how I can reach this settings?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where each option from the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lEpJ.jpg) refers to. Here's a working tutorial - *How to create a script with similar menu.*

First you need to install `dialog`. This application provides a method of displaying several different types of dialog boxes from shell scripts:

```
sudo apt install dialog
```

Then create executable file, let's call it **`smenu`**, and place it into the directory `/usr/local/bin/`, thus it will be accessible as shell command system wide:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/smenu
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/smenu
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/smenu
```

The script content should look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
HEIGHT=18
CHOICE_HEIGHT=10
WIDTH=78
BACKTITLE="SYSTEM MENU"
TITLE="[ M A I N - M E N U ]"
MENU="Tasks:"

OPTIONS=(
Network/IP   "IP Settings         [sudo nano /etc/hosts                ]"
Network/DNS  "DNS Settings        [sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf          ]"
Network/IFCS "Network Interfaces  [sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces   ]"
Timezone     "Set Time Zone       [sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata        ]"
Reboot       "Reboot the System   [sudo systemctl reboot               ]"
Shutdown     "Shutdown the System [sudo shutdown                       ]"
Logout/Exit  "Logout the Session  [logout                              ]"
Update       "Update & Upgrade & autoRemove & autoClean   [sudo apt ...]"
Edit         "Edit this script    [sudo nano /usr/local/bin/system-menu]"
Shell        "Exit to Shell"
)

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
    --title "$TITLE" \
    --menu "$MENU" \
    $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
    "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
    2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
    Network/IP)
        sudo nano /etc/hosts
        ;;

    Network/DNS)
        sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
        ;;

    Network/IFCS)
        sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
        ;;

    Timezone)
        sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
        ;;

    Reboot)
        sudo systemctl reboot
        ;;

    Shutdown)
        sudo shutdown
        ;;

    Exit)
        logout
        ;;

    Update)
        sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
        echo "**"
        sudo uname -a
        echo "**"
        sudo lsb_release -a
        echo "**"
        [ -e /var/run/reboot-required* ] && echo "Reboot is required!" || echo "Reboot is not required."
        ;;

    Edit)
        sudo nano /usr/local/bin/smenu
        ;;

    Shell)
        exit
        ;;
esac
```

- Copy the above content and use in `nano`: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for exit.
- All commands used within the script are available in Ubuntu 16.04.
- The content between the brackets `[...]` is just a reminder of what will be executed.

Now you will be able to access the script via the command **`smenu`**. The result should be:

[image]

If you want to open this script after login into a terminal, append next line to the bottom of the file `~/.bashrc`:

```
/usr/local/bin/smenu
```

---

Instead of `dialog` can be used the tool `whiptail`, that offers much of the same functionality (and options) as `dialog`, and is installed by default in most Ubuntu distributions. For this purpose use the above script and change line `22` in this way:

```bsh
CHOICE=$(whiptail --clear \
```

Now the output of our script/command `smenu` should look like this:

[image]

Comment: `whiptail` offers much of the same functionality (and options) as `dialog`, and is installed by default. (I ran a quick test and you can just replace `dialog` with `whiptail` in this script, no unsupported options are used.)

Comment: @muru, thanks for this. I've updated the answer. I found that on my home Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 `whiptail` actually  was installed by default, but on my VPS with Ubuntu Server 16.04 (that is hosted on SolusVM/OpenVZ) it was not, so I ran `sudo apt install whiptail`.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. `whiptail` is a dependency of `ubuntu-minimal`, but not of `ubuntu-standard` or `ubuntu-server`. Strange indeed.

Comment: thank you guys so much, i'll try this next week and i'll reply thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi, @Devigner3D, have you succeed with this?